# C++ program functions arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

this program should work in microsoft visual studio

Function -> void inputScores(string[], double[][5]);

This function populates an array of strings with the names in the file.

This function populates a 2D array of doubles with the 5 scores associated with each name.

Function -> void computeAverage(double[][5], double&);

Function -> void computeLetterGrade(double, char&);

Function -> void printGrades(double[][5], string[], double, char);

printGrades should call computeAverage and computeLetterGrade.

The function prototypes using void return type are only suggestions.

There are always different ways to create a program.

You may change the function behavior if necessary or expedient to do so

students data are:

Ritch Blackmore,  85 95 57 78 56

Jimmy Page,   89 78 45 69 98

Pete Townsend,    93 56 67 67 45

Alvin Lee,    93 67 89 90 45

Pete Green,   89 34 56 78 98

Jeff Beck,    85 34 67 87 65

Eric Clapton,     95 34 56 65 87

David Gilmour,    90 67 89 90 98

Tony Iommi,   86 45 67 87 98

Carlos Santana,   95 56 78 96 56

Mark Knopfler,    75 54 67 76 87

Alex Lifeson,     80 56 76 87 98

Frank Zappa,      80 65 76 56 98

Mick Taylor,      85 45 65 76 87

Robert Fripp,     70 43 90 80 78

Peter Frampton,   83 45 65 76 54

Ry Cooder,    95 34 56 78 87

Keith Richards,   95 45 67 89 67

Joe Walsh,    95 45 78 90 45

Steve Hackett,    95 34 56 54 76

Comment: Don't be lazy. Do your own homework.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing somebodies homework

Comment: I tried many times, to do. I'm not lazy. i need help for that.

Comment: So where is the evidence of what you have tried?! BTW - Dd something with the format of the question to make it readable

Comment: give me your email I can send to you my program to see where I'm stuck on it.

Comment: what you mean about format?

Comment: @Johan - Mark the code blocks - i.e. use {} tool  etc.

Comment: @Johan - Use summat like codepad.org to give over the code

Comment: sounds like a homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would declare the functions the following way

```
const size_t SCORE_NUM = 5;
const size_t STUDENT_NUM = 100; // at least not less than the number of records in the file

size_t inputScores( std::ifstream &, std::string[], double[][SCORE_NUM], size_t );

double computeAverage( const double[], size_t );

char computeLetterGrade( double );

void printGrades( const std::string[], const double[][SCORE_NUM], size_t );
```

For example function computeAverage could be defined as

```
double computeAverage( const double scores[], size_t n )
{
   double sum = 0.0;

   for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) sum += scores[i];

   return ( n == 0 ? sum : sum / n );
}
```

It should be called for each row of the array of doubles.

The definition of function inputScores could look as (without testing):

```
size_t inputScores( std::ifstream &in, 
                    std::string students[], 
                    double scores[][SCORE_NUM], 
                    size_t n )
{
   std::string record;
   size_t i = 0;

   while ( i < n && std::getline( in, record ) )
   {
      std::istringstream is( record );

      std::string lastName;

      if ( is >> students[i] && is >> lastName )
      {
         students[i] += ' ';
         students[i] += lastName;
      }

      std::memset( scores[i], 0, SCORE_NUM * sizeof( double ) );

      size_t j = 0;

      while ( j < SCORE_NUM && is >> scores[i][j] ) ++j; 

      ++i;
   }

   return i;
}
```

Comment: I have question can I sprat this code into 3 files. for example header file, implementation file, and code file

Comment: Ok, I am trying to do it now once I finished I will tell you.

Comment: Excuse me Vlad  i got some errors when I tried to execute this code, I try to post in your forum but it is difficult to read language please give me your email.

Comment: @Johan  I do not discuss such questions by e-mail.  Try to write a post.

Comment: OK, see I got many errors when I execute this code.  please click this link to see the errors  http://codepad.org/tAAwJKwv

Comment: @Johan You must include all required headers.

Comment: I worte all files header  but still show me error

Comment: @Johan  You have to include header <sstream>. Without seeing the code i is difficult to say what is wrong.